# How to create MongoSchema dynamically in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm following this way.

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
Id : {type: String},
Name : {type: String}
}, {strict: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('account', mySchema);
```

It's working fine, but everytime i restart the server my collection wipe off automatically..
i'm using this way to get collection

```
const collections = Object.keys(mongoose.connection.collections); 
return res.status(200).json({status:true,msg:collections})
```

After restart the server collection shows empty, What is wrong i'm doing??

Comment: It very much looks like the issue is not connected to the code you have here. What other stuff do you have in your project? :)

Comment: Hii Joel, i've an API to create collection and also some predefine fields in that schema you can see Id,Name and that's what i have to do..so first block of the code is doing that JOB, But when it comes to get all the collection i created using API, this collections list shows empty if i restart the server, where MongoDb is already hosted on server so why is that erasing collection?? but on mongoDb Atlas i saw same collection i have..still list shows empty if my server went restart

Comment: Hmm, if Atlas works with the same code and your server does not, could it be that your server is running in the in-memory mode? That resets every time your memory resets https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/